# Executing mongodump command from bash script

Tags: mongodb, bash

I am trying to execute a mongodump command with a query from within a bash script, but I am getting unexpected failures.  The example below shows the problem:

```
mark@mark-XPS-13-9370:~/Projects/plait$ mongodump --host 127.0.0.1:27017 -d plait_live -o /tmp/test -c events --query '{organisation:{$exists:true}}'
2019-07-01T17:08:36.232+0000    writing plait_live.events to 
2019-07-01T17:08:36.233+0000    done dumping plait_live.events (232 documents)
mark@mark-XPS-13-9370:~/Projects/plait$ cat >> test.sh
CMD="mongodump --host 127.0.0.1:27017 -d plait_live -o /tmp/test -c events --query '{organisation:{\$exists:true}}'"
echo $CMD
$CMD
^C
mark@mark-XPS-13-9370:~/Projects/plait$ bash ./test.sh
mongodump --host 127.0.0.1:27017 -d plait_live -o /tmp/test -c events --query '{organisation:{$exists:true}}'
2019-07-01T17:09:33.943+0000    Failed: query is not in proper format
```

What am I not seeing / aware of?

Comment: Read [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: That said, the very, very short form: Code should be stored in *functions*; argument lists should be stored in *arrays*. Don't ever use *strings* as a substitute for either of those; unquoted string expansion has a bunch of behaviors you might not expect, but which are utterly necessary elements of the specification -- without them, it would be impossible for scripts written in shell-derived languages to handle untrusted data safely.

Comment: ...in particular, quotes (and other syntax) resulting from unquoted expansions are treated as *literal data*, not syntax; attempts to evade that using `eval` introduce serious security bugs, as discussed in [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: ...if you want to log what a script is doing, just put `set -x` in it, and it'll print every command before it runs in a format that can be copied and pasted back. `echo` isn't a reliable tool anyhow -- it's allowed to munge data badly; see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, and the (excellent) answer by Stephane to [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) on [unix.se]